# Looking for a model that can extract actions from a sentence

Tags: python, nlp

I was wondering if anyone knew of a model that can extract actions as well as the person performing the action from a sentence. An example of what I'm looking for:

```
Input: "Anna will send Bill an email detailing the next steps."
Output: {"person": "Anna", "action": "send Bill an email detailing the next steps"}
```

I've been trying with SpaCy and looking around on Huggingface but thought someone might know of a relevant model!